# Listas e dicionários python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou a trabalhar em Python 2.7.

```
import collections
counter_ger=collections.Counter(sub_todaas)
a=counter_ger.values()
b=counter_ger.keys()
sub_ind_novo = [Ntodos.index(i) for i in b if i in Ntodos]
```

(onde Ntodos contém muitos nomes, de entre os quais estão os que constituem a lista "b" e esta parte era para saber o indice deles quando ocorrem em "Ntodos")

```
#counter_ger=Counter({u'Fe60': 12, u'Falag60': 8, u'Pe60': 6, u'Chaf60': 4, u'Par': 4, u'Vila': 4, u'Per60': 4, u'Cast60': 4, u'Fala150': 3, u'Tab60': 3, u'Zez': 3, u'Pe220': 2, u'Chaf220': 1, u'Fe220': 1})
#a=[4, 8, 3, 4, 4, 12, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 6, 4]
#b=[u'Chaf60', u'Falaga60', u'Fal150', u'Par', u'Vila', u'Fe60', u'Pe60', u'Chaf220', u'Pe220', u'Tab60', u'Zez', u'Fe220', u'Pe60', u'Cast60']
#sub_ind_novo=[96, 101, 7, 42, 39, 99, 97, 23, 18, 94, 67, 68, 95, 100]
```

Para relacionar uma lista p_prod, com as anteriores, tendo os valores de b em comum usei isto:

```
def indicesDeElementoNaLista(elementoProcurado, lista):
    return [i for (i, elemento) in enumerate(lista) if elemento == elementoProcurado]

def elementosNasPosicoes(lista, posicoes):
    return [lista[i] for i in posicoes]

prod_barr = {}
elementosCorrespondentes=[]
for elemento in b:
    posicoes = indicesDeElementoNaLista(elemento, sub_todaas)
    elementosCorrespondentes.append(elementosNasPosicoes(p_prod, posicoes))
    prod_barr[elemento] = elementosCorrespondentes
Lista=[]
for i in elementosCorrespondentes:
    for j in i:
        Lista.append(j)
#Lista=[4.223212, 35.955, 28.54111, 6.69015, 2.004056, 9.731978999999999, 3.508121, 0.7185728, 27.90795, 0.31004020000000004, 4.372325, 0.8837922, 99.0, 116.0, 36.0, 1.066429, 4.588346, 53.5449, 0.6904233000000001, 11.350000381469727, 17.450000762939453, 11.0, 20.1200008392334, 1.711943, 3.012495, 0.2186731, 4.320139, 12.5081, 0.3079727, 22.61825, 16.73781, 1.014131, 26.747880000000002, 0.019620460000000003, 0.6058, 11.27064, 14.42632, 1.147464, 4.8489889999999995, 38.0, 229.0, 20.639999389648438, 5.87853, 32.93286, 73.79299, 60.0, 50.0, 105.0, 20.979999542236328, 0.8396113000000001, 12.70308, 1.2727460000000002, 3.1277649999999997, 0.1861473, 6.1493329999999995, 21.105880000000003, 4.862599, 91.31339999999999, 1.014135]
```

Precisava de ter o resultado na forma:
no96. G1 = 4.223212 
no96. G2 = 35.955 
no96. G3 = 28.54111 
...
no69. G1 = 0.08837922
no95. G1 = 99.000000
no95. G2 = 116

por isso fiz:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):

    if a[i]==1:
        print ("no%d. G1 = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],Lista[i]))

    else:
        for j in range(1,a[i]+1):
            print ("no%d. G%d = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],j,Lista[i]))
```

os valores de no e G dão bem, mas não sei como percorrer a lista "Lista" aí.. De facto o ciclo vai de 0 a 14 que é o tamanho de "a" e "Lista" tem 59 elementos. Mas como "a" é uma lista de ocorrencias, ao aparecer: G1, G2, G3, G4, até ao número dessa ocorrencia (elemntos de "a" a cada iteração) vai fazer os 59 no final!
Há alguma forma de fazer isto?

Comment: diga-me uma coisa... o que relaciona Lista com as outras listas que temos. Por exemplo o elemento num 15 de Lista, o que tem a haver com a lista `a`

Comment: Por exemplo os 4 primeiros valores de "Lista", são os valores de G1, G2, G3, G4 para a 1ª iteração do for, onde a!=1 e a==4. Ou seja, Chaf60 em "b", aparece 4 vezes em "sub_todaas" (lista que não tenho aqui mas acho que deve ser irrelevante) e corresponde a este 96 em "sub_ind_novo".
Assim devia aparecer:
no96.G1 = 4.223212
no96.G2 = 35.955
no96.G3 = 28.54111
no96.G4 = 6.69015
depois 
no101.G1 = 2.004056
...
mas tenho que ter atenção à condição de quando a[i]==1, em que só pode fazer G1 e tem que retomar a ordem de "Lista"

Comment: Acho que entendi... Dê-me uns mins

Comment: Porquê os primeiros 4 só? qual é a condição para passar para o valor seguinte de `sub_ind_novo`?

Comment: Esses 4 são os que pertencem à mesma chave do dicionário counter_ger, que neste caso é "Chaf60"

Comment: Estou aqui a tentar ajudar mas sinto que tenho poucos dados. Estou a tentar

Comment: Como é que eu sei que é para passar para o prox de `sub_ind_novo`

Comment: se for preciso mais alguns, alguma lista ou isso posso mandar, só evito mandar porque costumam ser extensas e depois pedem para resumir e simplificar as questões.. mas posso mandar! Obrigada!

Comment: Não é preciso aqui. Mas pode pôr no google drive ou http://www.filedropper.com/ que eu dou uma olhadela

Comment: sub_ind_novo é a lista que contém os indices em que os nomes que aparecem em b, surgem numa lista de muitos nomes (Ntodos) e servia apenas para poder preencher a parte do "no" e ficar concordante com o restante código que já tinha. Isso ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu percebi pode ser isso, veja se ajuda

```
count = 0;
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0,a[i]):
        if a[j]==1:
            print ("no%d. G1 = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],Lista[count]))
        else:
            print ("no%d. G%d = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],j+1,Lista[count]))
        count += 1
```

Ou seja, vamos percorrer `a` e dentro de cada iteração vamos `a[i]` iterações, ou seja na primeira vamos fazer `4` na segunda vamos fazer `8` etc... Ao todo vamos fazer 59 (`count`), o que calha bem com o número todas de items em `Lista`

Comment: Dá certinho, muito obrigada pela ajuda!!! @Miguel

Comment: De Nada @Sofia.

Comment: Eu acho que nos enganamos @Sofia, acho que a condição que quer é `a[i]==1` e não `a[j]==1`, veja como é

Comment: Obrigada @Miguel pelo reparo, nem tinha visto, entretanto encontrei outro problema e mudei, para fazer o que eu queria tem que ser assim:
count = 0;
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(1,a[i]+1):
        if a[i]==1:
            print ("no%d. G1 = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],Lista[count]))
        else:
            print ("no%d. G%d = %f \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],j,Lista[count]))
        count += 1

Comment: E deu certinho agora? Mas @SofiaRaimundo, por pedaço de código tu não vais usar o `j`, acho que podes só `for j in range(a[i]):` que vai fazer o mesmo numero de loops que `range(1,a[i]+1)`

Comment: Não experimentei, mas faz sentido, vou tentar! @Miguel